# MongoDb aggregation or mapreduce for invoicing statistics?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDb and have a job for (I suppose) MapReduce or Aggregation.

I have an "invoices" collection with documents in this format:

```
{
    date: 'some unix timestamp',
    total: 12345,
    paid: true
}
```

I need to display a table with months (jan-dec) as columns, a row for each year and the sum of total in the month (divided in paid and unpaid) in the cell. Like this:

```
     |     Jan     |      Feb      | ...
2013 | 1,222 / 200 |  175 / 2,122  | ...
...
```

Can you help me get the mongo command right?
Maybe I'm better off writing some JS code to execute in mongo?

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but it works better if you give a solid try at writing it yourself and then asking for help on the details rather than asking the community to write it for you.  Start with the aggregation framework unless you want to persist the result in its own collection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I totally agree with you. I'm really much of a learn-by-example guy and I couldn't find a decent example to get just the basic syntax.

In the meantime I got something working which eventually resultet in my own answer. The question is now whether this should be done with some other approach, maybe aggregation.

I find the mapreduce syntax very simple and straight forward.

Comment: If you like the mapreduce syntax then stick with it unless its performance isn't adequate.  The aggregation framework is typically faster.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I would like to try the aggregation framework as well, but don't have the time right now. I might come back and update the answer with the aggregation version some time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've now found a solution using MapReduce. Here it is in use from PHP:

```
$map = new MongoCode('
    function() {
        var d = new Date(this.date*1000);
        emit({y: d.getFullYear(), m: d.getMonth()}, {
            total: this.total,
            notPaid: this.paid ? 0 : this.total,
            count: 1
        });
    };
');

$reduce = new MongoCode('
    function(month, values) {
        result = { total: 0, notPaid: 0, count: 0 };
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            result.total += values[i].total;
            result.notPaid += values[i].notPaid;
            result.count += values[i].count;
        }
        return result;
    };
');

$result = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'invoices',
    'map' => $map,
    'reduce' => $reduce,
    'out' => 'temp'
));

echo $result['timeMillis'];
```

Now the results are in the "temp" collection, one document per month. Could it be optimized or enhanced?

Comment: excellent example of solving this via map/reduce. See my answer for aggregation framework solution (which will likely be a lot faster).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with aggregation framework like this:

```
db.invoices.aggregate( [
    {
        "$project" : {
            "yr" : {
                "$year" : "$date"
            },
            "mo" : {
                "$month" : "$date"
            },
            "total" : 1,
            "unpaid" : {
                "$cond" : [
                    "$paid",
                     0,
                    "$total"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "y" : "$yr",
                "m" : "$mo"
            },
            "total" : {
                "$sum" : "$total"
            },
            "unpaid" : {
                "$sum" : "$unpaid"
            }
        }
    }
] )
```

You can use another `$project` at the end to pretty-up the output, and a `$sort` to order it, but that's the basic functioning core of it.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it faster than mapreduce? And is it possible to use your example with me having dates as unix timestamps?

Comment: It appears that at the moment the aggregation framework $project does not have support for converting unix timestamp stored as long long directly into date type (which is what $year and $month expect).  You can still do it but it would be kludgy and convoluted - it would basically require using $project with {$cond:[{$lt:"$date", ISODate("2012-01-02T00:00:00").valueOf()}, "Jan-2012", {$cond:... etc}... to map all ranges of timestamps into appropriate "Year-month" strings you can then group on.

Comment: it's a lot faster than map/reduce because it runs natively on the server - map reduce has to spawn a JavaScript shell to run the code and also convert the data from BSON to JSON among other things.